# How to use two different Hibernate caching strategies for a couple of entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, caching

For my application, I'd like to use two different hibernate caching strategies for a couple of entities. Therefore (afaik, please correct me if I am wrong) using annotations on the entities like

```
@Cache(usage=ConditionalStrategy)
public class MyEntity{
...
}
```

will not work as "ConditionalStrategy" has to be a constant field (in order to be used with annotations).

I have seen how to configure the caching strategies per entity using the hibernate.cfg file 
(see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-mapping)
but I would like to set them directly using the JPA properties of the Spring LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, i.e.

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
Properties jpaProps = new Properties();
// what to put here to configure the caching strategies per entity?
jpaProps.put(..., ....) 
factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProbs);
```

How would I have to set the JPA properties to replicate the annotation based configuration? Is this even possible?

**UPDATE for those facing the same problem:** If someone runs into the same issues, also consider using the Spring Cache (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) abstraction instead of the hibernate annotations (which is what I have done in the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it makes no sense to use a `ConditionalStrategy` because the actual caching provider (e.g. Ehcache) only supports the four typical caching strategies:

- [read-only](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-read_only-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/)
- [nonstrict-read-write](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-nonstrict_read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/)
- [read-write](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/)
- [transactional](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-transactional-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/)

Hibernate allows you to set a default caching strategy as well:

```
hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy=read-write
```

and you can override it using entity-level annotations or the Hibernate specific XML configurations.

Anyway, you can't use a conditional caching strategy at runtime because the entity cache policy is built only once when the `SessionFactory` is started.

Comment: With respect to your last comment, the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory (LCEMF) Bean is created before the SessionFactory is started, isn't it? So using the LCEMF to set the default caching strategy should be no issue (I guess). But what I am looking for is to override the default strategy for particular entities using the LCEMF configuration as well.

Comment: The major obstacle you'll bump into is that JPA hasn't yet standardised the caching strategies, so they are only available through Hibernate specific mappings.